# How to apply cascading delete for many to many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding

I have a many-to-many relationship between three tables as shown.

[image]

when I apply migration to build and seed the phisical database I get that error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
> 'FK_Rooms_postSubjects_postSubjectId' on table 'Rooms' may cause
> cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
> UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index.

these three tables are implemented using Entity Framework Models and seeded to be cascaded on deletion as follows

**First: the three models (PostSubject, Room, AppUser)**

*PostSubject*

```
public class PostSubject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    // ... some props

    public virtual List<Room> rooms { get; set; }

    public string authorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("authorId")]
    public virtual AppUser author { get; set; }
}
```

*Room*

```
public class Room
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    #nullable enable
    public Guid? postSubjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("postSubjectId")]
    public PostSubject? postSubject { get; set; }

    #nullable enable
    public string? MemberId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MemberId")]
    public AppUser? Member { get; set; }
}
```

*AppUser*

```
public class AppUser: IdentityUser
{
    // ... some props

    public List<Room> rooms { get; set; }
    public List<PostSubject> postSubjects { get; set; }
}
```

**Second: the seeding logic to cascade deletion**

```
// delete one postSubject should be followed with deleting all related rooms
builder.Entity<Room>().HasOne(i => i.postSubject)
.WithMany(c => c.rooms)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

// delete one user should be followed with deleting all related rooms
builder.Entity<Room>().HasOne(i => i.Member) 
.WithMany(c => c.rooms)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

// delete one user should be followed with deleting all related postSubjects
builder.Entity<PostSubject>().HasOne(i => i.author)
.WithMany(c => c.postSubjects) // IsRequired means it's necessary to have the relation
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: There's no circular relation in that diagram. Which isn't an actual table schema either.

Comment: It's not about the title. You get that error because the actual relations are *not* those in the diagram. Where are the `AppUser` relations?

Comment: The issue is not with EF, this is a restriction of MS SQL. You cannot have two foreign keys on a table with ON CASCADE DELETE.

Comment: @juunas mmmm do you mean cascade delete can be applied just in case of One to Many? for example can I make cascade between PostSubject and Room and set null for AppUser and Room?

Comment: One of the Cascades has to be set to another option. Set null could work.

Comment: @juunas thanks bro I removed the second one between Room and AppUser "Member" and it works. using setNull or NoAction didn't work however if I need to delete a user and their related rooms I would use triggers instead as Panagiotis Kanavos has mentioned.